# How can I add custom data annotations to a dc.js chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, dc.js, crossfilter

I currently have a fairly basic composite line chart that looks like this:

[image]

I would like to add the following "dynamic" annotations to it:

[image]

By "dynamic" I mean that these totals and computed ratio need to be updated whenever the date filter is changed by the user, or there is a brush selection.

I am stuck on two aspects:

1. What is the recommended way to approach this? So far I have explored two paths:

   - Drawing SVG elements into the chart using a renderlet: I'm not able to access the crossfilter object to retrieve the data.
   - Create a custom D3 rendering outside of the chart: I'm not able to get the stats to update when the date selector is changed or the chart is 'brushed'. Also, this somehow reduces the flexibility of having the annotations within the chart itself (as far as I understand).
2. As an aside, can the ratio be computed directly in crossfilter? If so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have this mocked up, I would recommend just setting these up as separate charts. Probably the best option is to use [dc.numberDisplay](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.numberDisplay).

Regarding computing ratios - yes, you can compute them in Crossfilter, but don't do that. Maintain both components of the ratio on a single Crossfilter group (using custom reducers, [Reductio](https://github.com/crossfilter/reductio), or [Universe](https://github.com/crossfilter/universe)) and do the division at reporting time. In dc.js, this means calculating the ratio in the `valueAccessor` of the chart.

Comment: As you recommended, I was able to use the dc.numberDisplay and compute the ratios in the valueAccessor with a custom Crossfilter group. Thanks.